# Display Rails 6 show view as embed shopify page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have an app, which is hosted on heroku, already installed in my test shop and ready to use. The app is embed in the admin. The App creates a rails view, which shall appear embed in the shop frontend as a page, like it would be created in the pages section by a shop admin.

Ive read about app bridges and app proxies which in my opinion dont give me the functionality I want.  One thing I came along is building iframes on the fly on an API-created page, but i dont know if its the best way to accomplish it.

App functionality:

1. App does something in the shopify admin and creates a link - done
2. The link will be copied by the admin/user to his navigation - will be done manually
3. If a customer clicks on the link in the shop-frontend-navbar, the link shall open as a shopify-page, so that the user thinks he is still in the shop-frontend.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just considered *Raw App Proxies*, when you had to rule out App Proxies of your choice.

There is another type of App proxies that is interesting for your situation: [**App proxies with liquid response**](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension#proxy-response), which supports Shopify's template language. You can use Liquid within your proxy page **as if the page is a part of the online store's theme**, and the end user won't notice that the page has been proxied.

All you have to do is setting the HTTP response from the proxy URL to include

> **Content-Type: application/liquid**

in its headers,

When this happens, the end-user still sees www.your-store.com/apps/proxy in the address bar. However, the liquid contents are then rendered inside the merchant store’s active theme. This means that the header, footer, and URL remain true to the merchant store. The liquid contents are shoved in-between the header and footer, *allowing the app-proxy to display contents that look as if the merchant store is rendering them with styling intact.*

**Note:** Another important reason to reconsider App proxies over your current solution of creating a normal page, is that once the app has created and attached the page to the store, the merchant can uninstall your App at any time (**no reccuring revenue :(**) but the page will continue to function on the store, because the merchant owns the pages of his store.

With the App proxies it is different, once your App is uninstalled by the merchant the link will no longer work, one by shopify will stop proxying this link (404) and the other by you can deny access in your Back-end, because the merchant does not own the proxy pages, he only has guaranteed access to use them as long as the app is installed.